# excel group data on one page allowing for sorting but also updating (prefer no VBA)

Tags: excel

I would like to create a spreadsheet that has 3 types of data (list of students, list of teachers, list of parking), for example:

```
Students  Grade Parking_Lot
Joe       A     1
Carl      B     2

Teachers  Class    Parking_Lot
Mr. Bob   Science  1
Ms. Ann   Math     2

Name      Parking_Lot  Position
Joe       1            Student
Carl      2            Student
Mr. Bob   1            Teacher
Ms. Ann   2            Teacher
```

I don't want to enter names more than once. I figured I could edit the students and the teachers table, and create the parking table automatically. But then I can't sort the parking table as the entries are all formulas. I'd like to be able to sort by parking lot or name. I also would like to be able to change parking lot from any of the tables.

Is there any way to accomplish this without VBA? Am I thinking about this wrong?

Thanks,

Nachum

Comment: What formula was used?

Comment: I have looked up PivotTable, but it didn't look like it would help. Could you give me some ideas on how to do this with a PivotTable?

Comment: Check out my answer in [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331700/compiling-different-excel-sheets-without-a-macro/20333020#20333020) - you can most likely use the same approach here!

Answer (score 0):

Example with PT (using Count of Name for `Σ Values`):

[image: SO20256525 example]

Unfortunately referencing the parking lots with just `1` and `2` makes the PT more difficult to interpret.

Added some clarification.

`Position`, `Name` and `Grade` are Row Labels (in that order from the top), `Parking Lot` and `Class` are Column Labels, with Count of Name for Σ Values. I chose `Type` for the Report Filter and removed all Field Subtotals (click on each Field if necessary and select None) and in PivotTable Options, Totals & Filters removed the Grand Totals by unchecking Show grand totals for rows and Show grand totals for columns. Note that the PT is driven by the source data – not vice versa. Changes to the source data will be reflected in the PT (after Refresh) but you can’t edit data cells for fields in the row, column, or page area of the PT.

Comment: Can you put link up for sample excel file? I don't know how you made that. Also, I want to make sure that an update to parking lot in the pivot table updates the relevant entry in the other tables. Thanks!

Comment: Not really. The issue is that I need to be able to change the same data from the secondary view (pivot table in your answer). Turns out that the only way to accomplish what I want is by using a single page and creating custom views. That is what I am doing now.