# Compiling Different Excel sheets WITHOUT a macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have 4 different sheets with similar data, but in different formats. As an example:

**Sheet A**

```
Date        Buy-In     Game    Winnings
11/25/2013  $10        NFL     $18
11/28/2013  $10        NBA     $0
```

**Sheet B**

```
Sport       Buy-In     Date         Winnings
NFL         $5         11/26/2013   $9
NBA         $2         11/29/2013   $3.60
```

**Sheet C**

```
Buy-In      Game     Date         Winnings
$5          NFL      11/24/2013   $9
$2          NFL      11/21/2013   $3.60
```

**Sheet D**

```
Sport       Buy-In     Date         Winnings
NFL         $5         11/20/2013   $9
NBA         $2         11/22/2013   $3.60
```

I want to combine them into one sheet **without** using a macro. So the combined sheet would look like this:

**Combined Sheet**

```
Game      Date        Buy-In      Winnings
NFL       11/20/2013  $5          $9
NFL       11/21/2013  $2          $3.60
NBA       11/22/2013  $2          $3.60
NFL       11/24/2013  $5          $9
NFL       11/25/2013  $10         $18
NFL       11/26/2013  $5          $9
NBA       11/28/2013  $10         $0
NBA       11/29/2013  $2          $3.60
```

Is this feasible or even possible?

Comment: a macro would be more suitable for this

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the goal is to make this as accessible as possible for multiple users. I was hoping to do it without macros because not every user will be able to use them. But if macros are the only way I guess that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: you can reference data from other sheets and sort it..

Comment: Can you use Power Query?  Power Query has easy merge/append functionality, and the end result is that the final data is in a table on a worksheet. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

Comment: I would create 4 sections on the combined sheet, 1 for each source sheets. Then add an indicator column that will distinguish useful rows from "empty" ( `LEN(..)=0`) ones. Now find the next useful section (combine `IF` and `MATCH` for example) and next the useful row (same way) in that section and use an `OFFSET` function to retrieve the data. Whenever you have done something please create a new question or update this one.

Comment: Easier would be to add the indicator column already in the 4 source sheets, I am thinking a counter, so your combined sheet can easily find the number of useful rows from the source sheets.

Comment: Without more details on what you're trying to actually do, and what format is acceptable in the end (and how to handle edge cases, how many lines you actually have, etc.) this is not really possible to answer. If you only have two lines per sheet, and always 4 sheets, it is easy. But if the number of sheets varies, or the number of lines varies, you end up with a far more complex answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `INDIRECT`function and a support table!

First you need to build a small support table that keeps the parameters for each input sheet:
[image]

- In column B, use the following formula to determine the number of rows: `=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'"&A5&"'!A:A"))-1`.
- For the range C5:F8, I used the formula `=MATCH(C$4,INDIRECT("'"&$A5&"'!1:1"),0)` - this will work for all columns that have the "proper" column name - only C6 and C8 needed to be entered manually, as you used "Sport" instead of "Game" here

Based on this support table, you can build your consolidation table. This has two sections - again 3 support columns to determine the sheet and the row number - and the data columns:
[image]

Use the following formulas:

- Column H: `=IF(ISTEXT(H4),1,IF(I5=1,H4+1,H4))` Logic: start with 1 and increase by 1 every time the row Id is reset to one - else keep the sheet ID from above
- Column I: `=IF(ISTEXT(I4),1,IF(I4=J4,1,I4+1))` Logic: start at 1 and increase by 1 until row ID in the row above is equal to the number of rows in the sheet from above. In the case, restart at 1

  - Column J: `=INDEX($B$5:$B$8,H5)` - get the number of rows for the current sheet from the config table
  - Column K:N: `=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&INDEX($A$5:$A$8,$H5)&"'!A1"),$I5,INDEX(C$5:C$8,$H5)-1)` - This is where the magic happens! ;-) Logic: Get the sheet name from the config table, use this in the INDIRECT function to retrieve the cell A1 from that sheet. Then offset by the row ID from the support column - and by the column ID for that sheet retrieved again from the config table.

See the example implemented in [this file](https://mega.co.nz/#!WIAGDLRB!ZPLV6Ef_2y6kmFSw2WukVgOWsGw0kIWYzw-fdaaGRUc)!